# Default value for a particular value retrieved from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Employee table have id, cmpId, name, designation, type

```java
@Query("select emp from Employee emp where emp.cmpId= :cmpId")
List<Employee> findById(@Param("cmpId") long cmpId);
```

here it will receive all the data from the employee table.

Now I want to retrieve the data id,name and designation as from the DB and for the type it should be always "PERMANENT" even if the value in the DB is any.

**How to do this only with the query ?**

**NOTE:** I cannot use the POJO getter to set the value as default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing this,

```
@Query("select id, name, designation, 'PERMANENT' as type from Employee emp where emp.cmpId= :cmpId")
List<Employee> findById(@Param("cmpId") long cmpId);
```

This will fix the values for the type column.